# Is it possible to remove the content editor (RTF field) for a certain user / role?

Tags: content, editor

As per the title really, I'm wondering if there's a way to hide the main content editor for posts and pages from certain users / roles but let everyone else see it?

I believe you can hide it completely using this code

```
function remove_pages_editor(){
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}   
add_action( 'init', 'remove_pages_editor' );
```

but I wouldn't have the first idea of how to adapt that so that it only affect certain users / user roles?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually why is it when I ask these things I come across the answer?

Not the exact answer I was after but found how to hide the content editor completely so then just put in a check for a certain user ID and it's working.

Pretty sure this wouldn't do anything harmful anywhere as it's just hiding the editor so nothing will be lost at any point hopefully?

```
function remove_pages_editor(){

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ($user->ID == 2) {
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    }
}   
add_action( 'init', 'remove_pages_editor' );
```